# What's wrong with this EF Join method call?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm currently restricted to using extension methods on an EF4 data repository; I can't use linq to EF.  I'm trying to make a simple 3 table join work.  Here is the code:

```
var query = _readOnlyRepository.All<Parent>()
            .Where( p => p.Something == "something" )
            .Join( _readOnlyRepository.All<Child>(), // Child entity
                p => p.ParentID,                     // Parent Key
                c => c.ChildId,                      // Child Key
                ( p, c ) => c )                      // Projection
            .Join( _readOnlyRepository.All<GrandChild>(),
                c => m.ChildID,
                g => g.GrandChildID,
                ( c, g ) => g )
            .Select( joined => joined.Child.Whatever );
```

Here is (essentially) the generated SQL:

```
select c2.Whatever
from Parent p
inner join Child c on p.ParentId = c.ParentId
inner join GrandChild g on c.ChildId = g.ChildId
left outer join Child c2 on g.ChildId = c2.ChildId
where ( "something" = p.Something )
```

What can I change in code to eliminate that left outer join that invalidates the intent of the query?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear exactly what you're attempting to return - the Whatever property of the GrandChild? Your second join returns the GrandChild object `( c, g ) => g` so I think you'd just need

```
.Select( joined => joined.Whatever );
```

because here `joined` is the GrandChild object.

Comment: Well, as I understand it, "joined" is the parent object along with joined children; the result of the first call to All() after filtering through Where().  That's why I have joined.Child.Whatever.  Intellisense agrees; it has Parent properties, not GrandChild properties.

Comment: I was thinking that the final result was the parent object, not the result of the last join.  I was accessing joined.Child thinking I was going parent -> child, but that property was actually the reverse: grandchild -> child.  The fix was to change ( c, g ) => g to ( c, g ) => c in order to return child not grandchild.